# Missing events in custom dstore using WebSocket and dgrid

Tags: javascript, websocket, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I am trying to create custom Store, which should use WebSocket or REST (in case of WebSocket failure).

Code file [rachet-store.js](https://github.com/sallyx/dojo-build-example/blob/rachet/js/rachet-store.js)

It works almost perfectly. It works without problems with the REST also (myRest).

Problem is if the wsStore is used and If i delete a row on first or second page in the datagrid, the datagrid is notified and refresh itself. But if I delete a row on the third or any other page, the store is not refreshed.

I think the problem could be somewhere with the `sort()`, because using that how the Grid (or Pagination) works. (But its just a guess ...)

So, the question is, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you host a functioning example somewhere ? It needs some debugging to be able to help you

Comment: Unfortunatellly I cant. But I have craeted README on the github with install instructions. It is easy and quick :)

Comment: Maybe your guess is correct. But the pagination is a server side functionality where the delete event which triggers for all rows may not be bound to the records in third/ future page elements.. try to render the grid for every page navigation

Comment: @ABUdhay This could help, but I'd like to know how to properly write dojo Store so It works well with datagrid.

Comment: Try sort function `this.inherited(arguments)` as `this.inherited("sort", arguments);`

Answer (score 1):

dstore provides a flexible selection of stores out of the box, but sometimes, it is necessary to create a custom store to better suit the needs of an application. This is a tutorial for doing just that. For our example, we create a store around the GitHub API v3 for Gists.

http://dstorejs.io/tutorials/custom_stores.html